# Adding an Int validation in a Do while loop validation

Tags: java, loops, validation, do-while

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*; 

public class ICT2100_LabTutorial2 {
    public static void main(String args[]){

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter your title: ");

        String title = input.nextLine();

        int page;
        int counter = 1;

        String value;

        do{
            System.out.println("Chapter " + counter++);
            value = input.nextLine();
            if(value.length() > 44)
            {
                System.out.println("More than 44 characters");
            }

            System.out.println("Enter a page number: ");
            page = input.nextInt();

            while((page < 1) && (page > 1500)){
                System.out.println("Enter a page number that is between 1 to 1500: ");
                page = input.nextInt();
            }

        }while(!value.equals("END"));

        System.out.println("you ended the process");
    }
}
```

I am trying to add page number into my code whereas the code will tell the user to enter the page number once again if it is not a number that's either 1 to 1500.

I am able to run the code properly and can end the program without the page counter, but the program breaks or doesn't run as intended once I added in the page counter segment.

Edit: So apparently you will have to add `input.nextLine();` after `input.nextInt();` for the program to actually go ahead and fetch the next instruction instead of being stuck in a loop. Correct me if I am wrong, still learning and thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
while((page < 1) || (page > 1500)) {
...
}
```

Comment: This will print out the error message if the user has supplied a number between 1 and 1500. The author is looking to have the error message printed when the user enters a number outside of the 1 - 1500 boundary.

Comment: @JohnStark Thanks, I have corrected the while condition accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Or condition instead of and

```
while(page < 1 || page > 1500)
```

Both conditions cant be true at the same time that's why remove && with || as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

You are using an `AND operator` which returns true when both conditions are true. But in your case it should return true when either of conditions inside `while loop` is true which is what `OR operator` does.

So use `OR operator (||)` isnide the while loop

```
while((page < 1) || (page > 1500)){
}
```